# Not possible to drush sql-sync sqlite to mysql pragma

Tags: drush, database

I have a local testing setup where I can create drupal sites easily, all running with a sqlite DB.

I want to (firstly) publish the site to a remote server using a script that calls

```
drush sql-sync @blah.livesite.local @blah.livesite.com --create-db
```

The problem i ran into is that `drush sql-sync` does not like to migrate a sqlite DB to a mysql DB as some structural deficites block the transfer. The error message is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
the right syntax to use near 'PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF' at line 1
```

I know I maybe can do a sql-dump first, edit some of the lines manually and import that filt into the remote db then.
But I need this procedure quite often and have an automation script for the transfer - it should work fast with no manual editing involved.

Is it not possible to sql-sync from sqlite to mysql generally?

Yes, and I tried [dbtng-migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/dbtng_migrator) as well, with help of [there](https://www.drupal.org/node/2223317). It did not work, I ran into all kind of errors, and I don't want to create another mysql db locally and sync then.

All I want is a simple way to sync my local sqlite drupal install to a remote  mysql one.

Comment: I'd be surprised if Drush has functionality to convert your data between arbitrary DBMS formats. I suspect you'll need to implement the conversion manually as part of your deployment workflow. Tools do exist to convert between sqlite and mysql, but no, they're not 1-to-1 compatible

Comment: OK, can  you post that as answer so i can mark it as correct...

Comment: But I still find it awkward that drush isn't capable of doing this. Drupal itself is DB agnostic as well, why doesn't drush also use a higher level api for `sql-sync`?

Comment: Which higher level Api are you referring to? I guess there may be one in existence but cross-converting data between all supported DBMSs doesn't seem like something Drupal (nor Drush) should be expected to do. Drupal supports different DBMSs; I'm not familiar with any claim that it supports converting data between those systems. It's an unusual requirement, one's production and development environments should traditionally be identical

Comment: Er, I just thought: [Drupal DB API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/database) `The Drupal 7 Database API provides a standard, vendor-agnostic abstraction layer for accessing database servers. The API is designed to preserve the syntax and power of SQL as much as possible, but also...`

Comment: Which bit of that suggests that it will **convert data** between different DBMSs? I think you're confusing support for drivers of a particular DBMS with support for converting data between them. These are entirely different concepts

Comment: Um,yes,that's true. Didnt think that far... sql-sync basically just does a dump and reads that in again...

Comment: You also may be confusing what happens when you run an sql-sync, though I admit I'm guessing somewhat as I haven't checked. I would imagine that Drush doesn't script the entire database using DBTNG (for obvious performance reasons), it dumps an sql archive using a tool provided by the DBMS that the data is installed on. A MySQL archive is not compatible with SQLite, so....

Comment: But ARE there tools that convert sqlite <> mysql on the CLI? I mean, to solve my first problem?

Comment: Of course :) I'm not sure there's anything Drupal-specific but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124437/mysql-to-sqlite-conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drush sql-sync cannot convert and sync databases in one step; however, you can use [drush dbtng migrator](https://www.drupal.org/project/dbtng_migrator) to convert the database locally into mysql format, and then use sql-sync to copy it to the final destination.